# Twitter Search API

Tags: twitter

How come when I do a search through the Twitter API, the results are so delayed, as opposed to how it is on the search.twitter.com?

I am writing a little joke script that responds to people in real time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to do real-time responding you may want to look in to [Twitter Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api). You can use the filter method and supply 'track' keywords that function much like search but the result are streamed to you in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy and timeliness of the Twitter Search results depend on a number of things, such as which server you hit, whether or not the result has been cached, whether or not the search you are doing is a trending topic (Twitter will curate the timeline for trending topics), etc.

The API at search.twitter.com and the website search.twitter.com are both on the same machines, and so any difference in reporting is due to individual variance in the webserver you hit, rather than any difference between the API and HTML version.